# changes not reflected in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate

I am trying to print some code in the controller of my application to debug but it's not reflected at the time of execution. I put a sys out statement in my controller and its printed.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Edit",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doActions(@ModelAttribute Project project,BindingResult result,Map<String,Object> map) {
        Project projectresult = new Project();

        Date date = new Date();

        String modifiedDate= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
        project.setSubtrack((subtrackService.getAllsubtrackByName(project.getSubtrack().getSubtrack())).get(0));
        project.setSubmittedDate(modifiedDate); project.setApprovedDate(modifiedDate); project.setCreatedDate(modifiedDate);
        project.setCreatedBy("r1"); project.setLastModifieddate(modifiedDate); project.setLastModifiedby("r1");
        String action = "edit";
        System.out.println("this is a test on the first place" +project.getEndDate());
        System.out.println("this is a test start Date" +project.getStartDate());
```

the second last line printed fine. But when I added the last line, it's ignoring it at all. I tried to debug the code restarting the server, and added the break points. Control is coming on the last line but it's not printing anything.

Comment: Please try clean, build and rerun your project.

Comment: Yes. Try Project > Clean.. Also, make sure you have "Build Automatically" enabled.

Comment: also try "System.out.flush();" after the last line. I'm not sure if this is the real problem, but what the hell!!! :P

Comment: I tried to clean the project but was it didn't work. I restarted the Eclipse and the expected results are shown again. Now the changes are reflecting.  Thanks everyone for your valuable comments.